# Send an image via NFC to an e-paper NFC module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, nfc

So I need to make an app that sends and image over NFC to an NFC module connected to an e-paper display. The image is generated in the app and is stored in a bitmap and a bytearray. So far I tried doing it like this:

```
sendButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_sendImage)
sendButton.setOnClickListener {
    nfcAdapter?.let {
         if(!it.isEnabled)
              openNfcSettings()
         else
              sendNfcMessage(imageByteArray)
    }
}

private fun createNdefMessage(image: ByteArray): NdefMessage {
    val mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("image/jpeg", image)
    return NdefMessage(mimeRecord)
}

private fun sendNfcMessage(image: ByteArray) {
    val ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(image)
    nfcAdapter?.setNdefPushMessage(ndefMessage, this)
}
```

This obviously didn't work. I also tried hardcoding the image from the gallery:

```
var fileName = "fasf.jpg"
var fileDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
var fileToTransfer = File(fileDirectory, fileName)
fileToTransfer.setReadable(true, false)
var fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileToTransfer)
val uri = Uri.fromFile(fileToTransfer)
val uris = arrayOf(uri)
if(fileUri == null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Nije pronadeno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
else
    nfcAdapter.setBeamPushUris(uris, this)
```

If it means anything this is the NFC module I am using: https://www.good-display.com/product/390.html
This is my first kotlin project using NFC and I really need some help/guidance on how to do this. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What Android version are you using? As those API's were removed in Android 10 and were part of Android Beam. Also is the Device programmed to receive Android Beam messages?

Comment: @Andrew I am using android 13. As for the Android Beam support on the module I don't currently know. I have asked the manufacturers and am waiting for their response. Are there any other ways of implementing the NFC sharing without using Android Beam? If there are would you be kind enough to share the documentation or any other sites that describe it? Thanks!

Comment: A quick look at the link suggests that they provide a library to send pictures via NFC, so you just need to use that in your project (there also seems to be a demo App, so you could check that out on your Android 13 phone as well). You could use Host Card Emulation on Android but you have to match what the Device is expecting (or program the device to match what you are doing in Android)

Comment: @Andrew I looked at the demo app and didn't find anything to help me build my own. For the libraries I though they just contained drivers and software for the module to work, but maybe I am wrong, I'll look into it tomorrow. Maybe I was just blind and overlooked it. If that's the case sorry for bothering you and thanks for your help!